# Variable from JS to PHP using AJAX - *Undefined array key "profile_viewer_uid" in C:\xampp\htdocs\zkoska\ppp.php on line 2*

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I wanted to POST variable from JS file to PHP using AJAX. I have both these files in same folder but when I run php code, I don´t see: Warning: *Undefined array key "profile_viewer_uid" in C:\xampp\htdocs\zkoska\ppp.php on line 2*

Why would be *profile_viewer_uid* undefined if I have it in JS and code also contains connection: *url: "PPP.php",*
What is wrong here?
Thank you

javas.js

```
<script>
var profile_viewer_uid = 1;
$.ajax({
  url: "PPP.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { "profile_viewer_uid": profile_viewer_uid }
}) 
</script>
```

ppp.php

```
<?php
 $profile_viewer_uid = $_POST['profile_viewer_uid'];
 echo($profile_viewer_uid);
 // prints 1
 ?>
```

Comment: Don't run the PHP code, run the JS code. The JS code will make a POST request which will fill the $_POST array at the time the request runs. This does not in any way extend into the future or magically reads code from other files.

Comment: Also note that you are in no way handling the response; you also need something like `success: function (response) { alert(response); }` in your ajax call.

Comment: If you *do* want to retain this value you also need PHP's `session_start()` and `$_SESSION`

Comment: @ChrisG After opening javas.js I see only my code.

Comment: @ChrisG _success: function (response) { alert(response); }_ should be where? Could you write the code? Thank you

Comment: You should look this up in the docs. Learning how to figure out things on your own is the most important skill when it comes to programming. Here's a short example: https://jsfiddle.net/8vqLthek/